# How to create typescript object that has both dynamic and statically typed properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have data coming from a server in the following structure. The structure is not ideal but it cannot be altered. Each object always has an `_id` property and then has limitless dynamically indexed objects.

```json
{
  "_id": : "123456",
  "5678" : {
     "associatedIds" : [567, 675, 756]
  },
  "6789" : {
     "associatedIds" : [678, 786, 867]
  },
  ...
}
```

This is the closest I can get to creating a type for it but it's not quite right. I get the error `Property '_id' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ associatedIds: number[]; }'`

```
type Data = {
  _id: string;
  [someId: string] : {
    associatedIds: number[];
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have control, at all, of the structure, you could move the dynamic keys into their own sub-object

Comment: If the dynamic properties are always numeric strings then you can give it a numeric index signature as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N75DnW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the structure and can change it, one option is to do this:

```js
type Data = {
    _id: string,
    data: {
        [someId: string]: {
            associatedIds: number[];
        }
    }
}

const x: Data = {
    _id: "",
    data: {
        "5678": {
            "associatedIds": [567, 675, 756]
        },
        "6789": {
            "associatedIds": [678, 786, 867]
        }
    }
};
```

Another way is, if your dynamic keys will always be numbers, do this instead: `[someId: number]` -- that works even if the real ids will come as numeric strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this with a `Record` where each value of the record is bound to a specific type of key:

```
type Associate = Record<string, { associatedIds: number[] }> | Record<"_id", string>;

const associate: Associate = {
  _id: "123456",
  "5678": {
    associatedIds: [567, 675, 756],
  },
  "6789": {
    associatedIds: [678, 786, 867],
  },
};
```

Another approach, thanks to @jcalz pointing out that this breaks the types when trying to reference properties, is to do an ugly cast to unknown, but with a strictly typed intersection:

```
type Associate = {
  associatedIds: number[];
};

type Data = {
  _id: string;
} & Record<Exclude<string, "_id">, Associate>;

const data: Data = {
  _id: "123456",
  "5678": {
    associatedIds: [567, 675, 756],
  },
  "6789": {
    associatedIds: [678, 786, 867],
  },
} as unknown as Data;

data?._id.toUpperCase(); // _id is a string
const x = data?.["5678"]?.associatedIds; // associateIds are number[]
```

Comment: That doesn't require the `_id` key.

Comment: @jcalz nope, but since it's coming from a data source, it's not like that key won't ever be there? Probably can do something fancy with generics with a required key `T` and `T extends keyof typeof "_id" ? T : never` but I have not had enough coffee for that.

Comment: And how do you propose dealing with the fact that `associate._id` isn't known to be a `string` to the compiler?  It thinks it's `string | number[]`, so `associate._id.toUpperCase()` is an error

Comment: Yuck, ok that's gnarly, good catch. Best I could do, updated.

Comment: ☕/0 is my enemy @jcalz

Answer (score 0):

[Typescript does not support this currently](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) because you are trying to use an index signature (`string`) with another key (`_id`) of the same type (`string`).

Assuming you cannot alter the structure coming from the server and your goal is to type this incoming data, you'll only be able to accomplish by "hacking typescript".

An idea is to use `symbol` instead of `string` as key type for `_id` field. [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) are different from `strings`, so typescript will not complain. It would look like this:

```js
const _idKey: unique symbol = '_id' as any;

type Data = {
  [_idKey]: string;
  [someId: string]: {
    associatedIds: number[];
  }
}

const x: Data = {
  [_idKey]: '123',
  "1234": {
    associatedIds: []
  }
};
```

The problem when using this solution is that you'll always need the `_idKey` variable to access the `_id` field on `Data`.
If you try to access directly using `Data['_id']`, typescript will wrongly say that it's `{ associatedIds: number[]; }`